# Destroy all thread before open another wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using multiple thread in wpf windows.

I am using `this.Close()` to close the window, and open another window using `newWindow.Show().`

Code:

```
// open new windows
newWindow newWindow = new newWindow();
                this.Close();
                newWindow.Show();

// close window
    private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // stop some events
                d.StopEvents();
        }
```

It will takes long time to reach `StopEvents`.

If I use `Environment.Exit(0)`; it will close the application, I don't want that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more clear about the question you are posing.

Comment: Have you considered keeping track of your threads in a `List<Thread>` and calling `Abort` on them?

Comment: You really don't want to be using `Abort` unless you have no other choice as without very careful usage you may as well consider the method to be called, `PleaseCorruptMyApplicationStateRandomly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are your threads doing? A common pattern is for working threads to periodically check a flag to see whether they need to close themselves. It's much safer for each thread to do that than for another tread to abort it.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider using the Parallel extensions (TPL) as this makes threading much easier, and comes with concepts like Cancellation baked in.

[.NET 4 Cancellation Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx)